# php while() loop within if / else not seeming to work

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop

I've been confused about why this wont work! My query executes perfectly fine in all aspects, but when I added the if check on the $row value, the echo message goes as expected (if there are no results), but the else will not kick when there is a match in my query??? Why is this not working? Someone please ease my pain and set me straight!!

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (!$row) {
    echo "Sorry brah. Nothing matches your search criteria.";
} else {

$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "$i - " . $row['first_name'] . " " .  $row['last_name'] . " - " .   $row['address'] . "<br />";
$i++;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);  // this fetches the first row your result
...
```

in while loop you are again fecthing thr row from result. Which will not work if you have only one row in resul

use

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "Sorry brah. Nothing matches your search criteria.";
} else {
    $i = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "$i - " . $row['first_name'] . " " .  $row['last_name'] . " - " .   $row['address'] . "<br />";
        $i++;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer. `mysql_num_rows($result) > 0`, should be `mysql_num_rows($result) == 0`. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

try  `mysql_num_rows($result)==0` instead in the if statement